# Blinking element in

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, intervals

Good day, all, so i'm doing this thing where i have 4 squares and when i click a button 3 random squares have to blink in different colors in sequence. And i need to store the id's of the squares that blinked in an array. What I can't figure out is how to make them blink one after another. This is what i have so far...https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dmBxYe?editors=0110

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        colors: ['yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'green'],
        quantity: 3,
    }
}
start() {
    const {quantity} = this.state;
    const quantityArray = Array.from(Array(quantity));
    const pieces = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.game-piece'));

    quantityArray.map((item, i) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            pieces[i].classList.toggle(`${this.state.colors[i]}`)
        }, 1000);
      pieces[i].classList.toggle(`${this.state.colors[i]}`);
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="memory-game">
            {this.state.colors.map((gamePiece, i) => {
                return <div key={`gamePiece-${i}`} className="game-piece"></div>
            })}

            <button onClick={this.start.bind(this)} className="start-game">Start the game</button>
        </div>
    )
}
}
React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want it to look like at the end, but just add another `setTimeout` when toggling the colors on:

```
quantityArray.forEach((item, i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    pieces[i].classList.toggle(`${this.state.colors[i]}`)
  }, 1000 * (i + 3));
  setTimeout(() => {
    pieces[i].classList.toggle(`${this.state.colors[i]}`);
  }, 1000 * (i))
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmVbdz?editors=0110

Also, unless you're mapping to a new array, use `forEach`, not `map`.

Comment: When i click the button, 3 random squares, one at a time, should blink(one after another).